# Forward Ports to a computer on the guest network (AirPort Extreme)

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, airport-extreme, time-capsule

Is it possible to forward ports (ex: 80, 443, 21, 22, 23, 25, 110, 143, 3389, ...) to a computer on the **Guest** network a of *AirPort Extreme* ??

I have the both network enabled and I want my child to remote desktop his computer from external. I need to forward the port `3389` to his computer but he's on the GUEST network, for security reason (don't ask please).

Is it possible?? It would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of things to map a port to the guest network, but it doesn't work. When I reboot the router to apply the modifications, the IP become `192.168.0.2` when I want `192.168.1.2`.

Small that can be interesting for the next AirPort Extreme or Time Capsule!